# Know minimal value in a sorted array, how to use binary search?

Tags: arrays, binary-search

Imagine you are given a sorted array which has been rotated, but you know the minimal value and its index in this array.

How do you write a binary search on this array?

example:

```
input array: [3,4,5,6,1,2]
search value: 4
min value index = 4
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done the same as you would do binary search on a sorted array without rotation, by applying a transformation to the index when you look up a test value:

```
testIndex = (searchIndex + minIndex) % arrayLength;
```

Where `searchIndex` is the index you would use if the array were not rotated, `minIndex` is the offset by which the array was rotated, and `testIndex` is the index you use to look up a value from the rotated array.

So in your example:

```
input array: [3,4,5,6,1,2]
minIndex: 4
first searchIndex: floor((arrayLength-1)/2) = 2
first testIndex: (4+2)%6 = 0
```

Comment: Hi starchild, in this case, how to deal with lo and hi pointer? In normal binary search, if nums[mid] < target, we will set lo = mid + 1 and if nums[mid] > target, hi = mid - 1 and lo <= hi. Thanks!

Comment: You still set `mid`, `low`, and `high` as you would in normal binary search. You only transform the index when you actually look up the test value in the array to do the value comparison.